# Where is my RDP server certificate stored?

Tags: security, remote-desktop, certificate, windows-server-2012

Given the recent issues of Man-in-the-Middle attacks, i actually paid attention to the warning i get when connecting to a server:

[image]

Selecting **View Certificate**, i was going to check the `SHA1` **Thumbprint**:

> **Issued to**: corsair
>   **Issued by**: corsair
>   **Valid from**: 9/5/2013 **to** 3/7/2014
>   **Thumbprint** (SHA1): `‎e9 c5 d7 17 95 95 fd ba 09 88 37 d8 9f 49 5e b8 02 ac 2b e2`

and make sure it matches whats on the server. i connected anyway, then using `certmgr.msc`, searched for the certificate (i.e. *"Issued to corsair"*):

[image]

There it is, the only one on the machine. But wait, that's not the same key:

[image]

The certificate i am presented through RDP is different than the one on the server:

> **Issued to**: corsair
>   **Issued by**: corsair
>   **Valid from**: 4/6/2013 **to** 8/7/3012
>   **Thumbprint** (SHA1): `‎c5 b4 12 0d f6 4f b3 e7 a8 59 cd 4d e4 0e cb 5b 18 a1 42 92`

Either there already is a Man-in-the-Middle, substituting fake certificates for RDP connections, or the certificate being presented by the RDP server is not visible in `certmgr.msc`.

Assuming i don't have CSIS monitoring my (non-domain) LAN: where can i find the certificate that RDP will present to connecting clients?

Server: Windows Server 2012 Standard

**Note**: Also applies to Windows 8. Also could apply to Windows 7, and earlier, and Windows Server 2008 R2, and earlier. Because even though, right now, i'm connecting to a server; i also connect to my Windows 7 desktop PC from the Internet - and i want to validate that i am seeing ***my*** actual desktop.

**Keywords**: How to change my Windows 8 Remote Desktop Connection SSL certificate? How to specify my Remote Desktop certificate?

Comment: 1.Are you using a your own domain CA server to create the SSL certificate or are you getting your SSL from a certificate Authority like Verisign? 2. Is the certificate you are showing in image 6mB6G.png from the a client or server?

Comment: @SamStephenson It's on the server. It's whatever certificate the server decided to create in order to let me remote to it; i didn't create it, ask it to create it, ask anyone else to create it, or have anyone else create it. i RDP to the server and the warning appears.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

#### In Windows 10

1. Search for `certlm.msc` in the Start Menu
   or using <kbd>Windows key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
2. Click on the **'Remote Desktop'** folder and then on **'Certificates'**. There you will find the certificate this computer presents to its RDP clients.

#### In Windows 7

1. Launch `mmc.exe` (as an administrator).
2. **'File'** -> **'Add/Remove Snap-in...'**.
3. Select **'Certificates'** in the **'Available Snap-ins'** list and click **'Add >'**.
4. A new window titled 'Certificates Snap-in' appears where you can choose from 'My user account', 'Service account' and 'Computer account'. 
   Choose 'Computer account', click 'Next', then 'Finish' and finally 'OK'.
5. Under the 'Console Root' folder you now have 'Certificates (Local Computer)'.
6. Click on the **'Remote Desktop'** folder and then on **'Certificates'**. There you will find the certificate this computer presents to its RDP clients.

You can then save this console view for easy access under 'File' -> 'Save'.

Comment: The REMOTE DESKTOP folder, I never saw that before! I kept looking in Personal and that's why I couldn't find it. Good catch!

Comment: thanks, worked perfectly for me :) Just that the Fingerprint in that Certificate window has 2 digits more at the start... weird~

Comment: Excellent! Didn't notice that `certmgr.msc` only shows certificates for current user, even if running as administrator.

Comment: Windows 10 seems to come with a shortcut `C:\Windows\System32\certlm.msc`. Since `System32` is in `$PATH` we can just search `certlm.msc` in Start Menu.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my answer with your solution

Answer (score 7):

This is answered [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/1b528a7b-882a-4dc0-bb63-e36968cc284d/selfsigned-certificate-for-remote-desktop-expired?forum=winserverTS):

> It (the **Remote Desktop Configuration** service) [...] created the certificate. Doing so generates an event log message:
>
> ```
> Log Name:     System
> Source:       Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager 
> ....
> Description: A new self signed certificate to be used for Terminal Server 
> authentication on SSL connections was generated. The name on this certificate
> is servername.domain.com . The SHA1 hash of the certificate is in the event
> data.
> ```

Go to `eventvwr.msc`, look up events by `TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager` in `System` and you will get all the different times when the RDP service (re-)created its server key, along with the SHA-1 hash of each key.

Comment: Odd that Microsoft would hide useful information behind a login, so thanks for sharing that with the rest of us.  On my Windows 7 machine, the name you want to filter events by is "TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager".  If you've already deleted that event log entry, you can always change the machine name to force a new certificate and event log message.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into this for servers and found a novel way to export the RD cert in powershell. Just passing it along.

`Get-ChildItem 'Cert:\LocalMachine\Remote Desktop\' | Export-Certificate -FilePath "$($env:USERPROFILE)\Desktop\RDcert.cer"`